# узнать цвет у view в android

Tags: java, android

Есть какой-то элемент view, у которого ползунком задается цвет. как мне узнать код этого цвета?

```
  ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
  int colorId = viewColor.getColor();
```

если воспользоваться данным фрагментом кода , то colorId - какое-то число в десятичной системе счисления, которое если выводить в логи ничего не дает (ну или я его не правильно использую)
Помогите пожалуйста ;)

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/catshop/color.php

Answer (score 1):

Цвет и есть число. В шестнадцатиричной системе выглядит как 0xRRGGBB, по два знака на красную, зелёную и синюю компоненты. Например, 0xFF0000 (десятичное 16711680) - красный.  Переводите получаемое число в шестнадцатиричное и смотрите какой цвет.